# Is it possible to change the namespace of an entity (NDB)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm wondering if it would be a simple way of implementing a "Trash Can" in datastore..

---

Sorry, my passing thought was that if it was an easy thing to change the namespace of an entity then you could have a namespace such as "deleted" which would hide entities from the main namespace but keep them easily restorable. I couldn't find anything in the docs but thought I'd put the question out there just in case..

Comment: The title of your question and the body don't match. please fix your question and provide more details about what do you mean by "trashcan"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namespace is part of the entity key, which can not be changed once entity is created. The only way is to create new entity, copy properties and delete the original.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's what I expected.

Comment: Is there an automatic way to copy to a new entity?